# delete elements with index greater then a clicked one

Tags: jquery

```js
$(document).on('click', '.crumb', function () {
var i = $(this).index('.crumb');
$('#path *:gt(i)').remove();
});
```

```css
.crumb{
display:inline-block;
margin:0 7px;
cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='path' id='path'>
<div class='crumb'>home</div>
<div class='crumb'>comp</div>
<div class='crumb'>display</div>
<div class='crumb'>reset</div>
</div>
```

I want to remove all elements from `path` with index greater then a clicked one.

So click on `display` should remove `reset`. Click on `comp` should remove `display and reset`. And so on.

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by using `nextAll`, check following :

```js
$(document).on('click', '.crumb', function () {
  var that = $(this);
  that.nextAll().remove();
});
```

```css
.crumb{
  display:inline-block;
  margin:0 7px;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='path' id='path'>
  <div class='crumb'>home</div>
  <div class='crumb'>comp</div>
  <div class='crumb'>display</div>
  <div class='crumb'>reset</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the jQuery `nextAll()` method to return all the siblings after the clicked one like so:

Check the Docs here: https://api.jquery.com/nextAll/

```js
$(document).on('click', '.crumb', function() {
  $(this).nextAll().remove();
});
```

```css
.crumb {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 7px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='path' id='path'>
  <div class='crumb'>home</div>
  <div class='crumb'>comp</div>
  <div class='crumb'>display</div>
  <div class='crumb'>reset</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jQuery.nextAll](https://api.jquery.com/nextAll/)

```js
$(document).on('click', '.crumb', function () {
    $(this).nextAll(".crumb").remove();
});
```

```css
.crumb{
display:inline-block;
margin:0 7px;
cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='path' id='path'>
<div class='crumb'>home</div>
<div class='crumb'>comp</div>
<div class='crumb'>display</div>
<div class='crumb'>reset</div>
</div>
```